# Assigning value only works outside the loop

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, reversing

I am learning CPP (first language) and I am trying to reverse a linked list.
this code is not working

```
node* reverse(node** head){
    node* previous=NULL;
    node* current=*head;
    node* nextptr=current->next;
    while(current!=NULL){
        current->next=previous;
        previous=current;
        current=nextptr;
        nextptr=nextptr->next;
    }
    return previous;
}
```

this one is working

```
node* reverse(node** head){
    node* previous=NULL;
    node* current=*head;
    node* nextptr;
    while(current!=NULL){
        nextptr=current->next;
        current->next=previous;
        previous=current;
        current=nextptr;
    }
    return previous;
}
```

Why does the second code snippet works while the first one doesn't ?

Comment: Not sure what's there to explain. One version updates the pointers correctly, the other one is not.

Comment: This is plain C, not C++. Consider editing the tags.

Comment: what should I do to make it look like cpp?

Comment: Well, in C++ you reverse a linked list like this: `std::list<int> list = { 8,7,5,9 }; list.reverse();`   :-)

Comment: To make it *look* more like C++, you could pass your parameters by reference.

Comment: In C++ there would be a class managing the linked list and hiding the existence of `node` from the caller. `node* reverse(node** head)` would look more like `void linkedlist::reverse()`. In C or C++, and probably any language, one of the best ways to understand linked lists is to draw pictures. Draw a small list. Follow your code exactly and attempt to reverse the list, redrawing the list at each step. When you find a spot where you cannot, you've found a bug and probably have a good idea what you needed to do instead.

Comment: Take out pen(cil) and paper, draw a list, and then update the drawing as you trace through your code. It's the best method to debug (and create) pointer-based data structures. (The first fails with both empty and single-element lists, so you don't need to draw very much.)

Comment: you should also learn how to use a debugger (gdb is a great tool)

Comment: @IgorR. If OP compiles this as C++, then it should be tagged C++. Otherwise potential answerers will have to way to know that they can suggest C++ features. Also the rules can be slightly different between the languages (not in this case though).

Comment: Thanks, @molbdnilo, I drew and understood. At the last node, the nextptr will be pointing to NULL, and the line nextptr=nextptr->next; inside while loop will cause ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the second code snippet works while the first one doesn't ?

The first snippet doesn't check before it dereferences potentially null pointers. Because you are using a null pointer to indicate the end of the list, it *always* dereferences a null pointer, and so has undefined behaviour.

The second snippet never dereferences a pointer it hasn't verified is non-null.